# Official German translators in India for visa processing

Tags: working-visas, germany, indian-citizens, paperwork

I am going to apply for a work visa for Germany. My future employer asked me for my university transcripts translated into German. They insist that it should be translated by a lawyer (certified translation) which I assumed that they want me to have notary stamp on the translation too.
I tried to find any lawyer with German knowledge or translation service with notary support in my city (Pune, India).
I don't know any German, thus can't translate it myself. Is there any such service available in Pune, India (or if available online in India)?

Comment: Is the original in English?  It will not be difficult to find a translator in Germany (or perhaps Austria or Switzerland) for documents in English.  For Hindi or another language it could be harder, but it is probably still not impossible.

Comment: You could try contacting the Goethe-Institut in Pune; they may know of a translator and a notary who can do this. https://www.goethe.de/ins/in/en/sta/pun.html